# Proper Sizing for Mainnet Chainlink Node on AWS

Tags: chainlink

This is a sizing question.

Chainlink docs say a min of 2 cores, 4 gigs of ram

AWS Chainlink quickstart defaults to 2 cores, 2 gigs of ram

What is the proper size for a mainnet production chainlink node?

Thanks

Chris

Anubis Soft

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to follow the official documentation of Chainlink: https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/

As you have already mentioned, 4GB ram is specified there as min requirements.

If you have too small amount of RAM left on your machine then the Chainlink node does not start cleanly and gets stuck in the initialization phase, as it can not execute and process the queries to the database.

"Of course, you can still try it with the AWS requirements"